# Which color scheme is this for sublime text?

Tags: themes, sublimetext2, syntax-highlighting

[image]

- Letter is Source Code Pro

this is the link: http://blogs.adobe.com/typblography/2012/09/source-code-pro.html

Comment: Check [ColorSublime](http://colorsublime.com/). Many nice themes there.

Comment: I would not put this on hold. Seems to meet the 'directly involve tools used primarily for programming' test to me. Sublime Text is a programmer's editor across windows, linux and OS X.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is a ST version of [SOLARIZED](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized).

There's a couple of these on github. [Sublime text theme dark solarized](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=sublime+text+theme+dark+solarized&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8).